# Using Python to graph student progress

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, graphing, plotly

I'm experimenting with python graphing for the first time and I want try what I've learned by graphing some of my student's progress. My progress data is in a table in a format the same as what I have mocked up below. I Have used MSPaint (sorry) to mock up what I think would be a decent graph to show them their progress.

What is the right name for this type of graph and what would be the first steps to achieve it? I can't see anything quite like it on http://matplotlib.org/ or on https://plot.ly/

Please feel free to tell me I am laying out the graph all wrong.
[image: Quick MSpaint mockup]

Comment: Maybe this can put you on the right track: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html G1, G2... could be your weeks, and the Men/Women are your students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a stab at generating your example chart in matplotlib.  I suspect others with stronger matplotlib-foo could greatly improve this :)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

students = ['steve', 'bob', 'ralph']
progress = [
[1, 3, 4, 4, 5],
[2, 3, 4, 4, 5],
[3, 3, 4, 5, 5]]

(fig, ax) = plt.subplots(1, 1)

# Offset lines by some fraction of one
dx = 1.0 / len(progress)
xoff = dx / 2.0
for i, (name, data) in enumerate(zip(students, progress)):
  ax.plot(np.arange(len(data)) + xoff, data, label=name, marker='o')
  xoff += dx

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, len(progress[0]) + 0.01, dx), minor=True)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(1, len(progress[0])+1))
labels = students * len(progress[0])
week = 1
for i,l in enumerate(labels):
  if l == students[1]:
    # hack to add Week label below the second label for each block
    labels[i] = "%s\nWeek %s" % (l, week)
    week += 1
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

ax.set_xticklabels(labels, fontsize=8, ha='left', minor=True)
ax.set_xticklabels([])
ax.tick_params(which='both', direction = 'out')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', width=4)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', length=7)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', width=0, length=0)

ax.set_ylim(0, 6)
ax.set_yticks(range(1, 6))

ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()

ax.set_title("Student Progress")

ax.legend(loc='best')

fig.show()
```

[image: example figure]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is probably what you are looking for

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

weeks = range(1,6)
steve = [1, 3, 4, 4, 5]
bob = [2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
ralph = [3, 3, 4, 5, 5]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(weeks, bob, label='Bob')
plt.plot(weeks, steve, label='Steve')
plt.plot(weeks, ralph, label='Ralph')
plt.title('Student Progress')
plt.ylabel('Score')
plt.xlabel('Week')
plt.xticks(range(6))
plt.ylim(0, 6)
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Giving each line a different dash style makes it slightly more obvious when two students have the same week-to-week (Bob is hard to pick out in this example -- week 4 to 5, how'd he do?)

Answer (score 0):

Try [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/). It supports categorical axes, and additionally supports datetime categorical axes ([docs link](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#datetime-axes))